# Spring MVC - Get access token

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-security-oauth2

I am adding OAuth2.0 to secure my WebAPI. I am trying to get a access token while user gets logged in. This is how i tried to get user info after logged in

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login/{username}/{password}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<User> login(@PathVariable String username, @PathVariable String password) {
        if (!username.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
            User user = userService.login(username, password);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
```

This is how i implement a code to get access token

```
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
          authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
          xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request 
        parameters -->
        <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
                       after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>
```

I can get access token manually when user hit a correct username and password.
Now i need to show User details with access token just like below

```
{ "userId":14, "fullName":"Nishan Dhungana",
"email":"justin@live.com", "address":"Hokse", "contact":null,
"dob":null, "active":false, "createdAt":1519196604347,
"username":"nishanjjj41", "password":"nishan123" , 

"value":"7f228939-5f8e-4c29-b2d9-9ac78d0c16d8",
"expiration":1519542443387, "tokenType":"bearer" }
```

Is this possible to get user details with access token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's a very bad idea to put the username and password in the url or send them back in a JSON. You don't need to send those again.

To send the additional information, you need to implement a custom token enhancer:

```
public class CustomTokenEnhancer implements TokenEnhancer {

@Override
public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
    User principal = (User)authentication.getPrincipal();
    Map<String, Object> additionalInfo = new HashMap<>();

    // add more additional info
    additionalInfo.put("user_name", principal.getUsername());

    ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo);

    return accessToken;
}
}
```

Then wire it into your configuration:

```
<bean id="tokenEnhancer" class="com.security.CustomTokenEnhancer" />

<bean id="tokenServices" 
 class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenEnhancer" ref="tokenEnhancer" />
    // more properties
</bean>
```

Comment: What is purpose of `CustomTokenEnhancer` class.

Comment: To send additional information about the user along with the token.

Comment: I have a another question how can i access the token value inside my controller